# phpMyAdmin not working in MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

I have recently installed MAMP but am unable to access phpMyAdmin, both that and SQLite Manager are greyed out in the menu:

[image]

Even when I try to load phpLiteAdmin, I get a `HTTP ERROR 500`

Going by the screengrab, it gives me the impression that I don't have my PHP at the correct version... but I've ran a `phpinfo()` test and I appear to have **PHP Version 7.1.1**

It might be worth noting that I changed the location of my *Document Root* to my Google Drive folder in the preferences panel

Do I need to modify some settings in MAMP to get this to work?

Comment: You have two options:1. download [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and set it up yourself. It isn't too bad, you just need to specify the database credentials in the configuration page. 2. Change the php-version that MAMP uses. Have you tried installing PHP in some other way before installing MAMP? Because version 7.1.x isn't officially supported yet, so it might be a leftover from a previous install. If you can, maybe remove PHP entirely from the system and install MAMP again?

Comment: @glaux switching php version fixed it, thank you!

Comment: great, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

Go in to preferences on MAMP and click on the php tab at the top. It defaults to your latest PHP version (I had 7.1.1 selected). Use the version which is compatible with phpMyAdmin - 5.5.x to 7.0.x
[MAMP > preferences > PHP (tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIHvp.png)

Hopefully this helps as it worked for me :)